# How to load GIF continuously on video in android using FFMPEG?

Tags: android, video, gif, android-ffmpeg

I tried this command for solving above issue but only load GIF once not in loop,

```
"-y", "-i", inputvideopath, "-i", inputgifpath, "-filter_complex", "[1:v]scale=1080:720[ovrl];[0:v][ovrl]overlay=0:0", "-frames:v", "600", "-codec:a", "copy", "-codec:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", finalvideoPath
```

I also tried with {"-ignore_loop", "0"} but video not create in exact time, it creates with extra time & GIF also loop continuously.

```
"-y", "-i", inputvideopath, "-ignore_loop", "0", "-i", inputgifpath, "-filter_complex", "[1:v]scale=1080:720[ovrl];[0:v][ovrl]overlay=0:0", "-frames:v", "600", "-codec:a", "copy", "-codec:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", finalvideoPath
```

Comment: HI can you please try adding `"-loop", "3"` command instead of `"-ignore_loop", "0",`

Comment: I already tried this "-loop", "3" but that isn't creating video and going on ffmpeg process failure

Comment: What are you getting as your error message?

Comment: Option loop not found & 
ffmpeg version n4.0-39-gda39990 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers  built with gcc 4.9.x (GCC) 20150123 (prerelease)

Comment: You are using video or gif as an input here? I can see 2 input paths

Comment: Video & GIf both are input and output is Video.

Answer (score 2):

try this command

```
String commnad[] = {
    "-y"
    , "-i"
    , inputVideo
    , "-ss"
    , "0"
    , "-t"
    , videoLength
    , "-ignore_loop"
    , "0"
    , "-i"
    , gifPath
    , "-filter_complex"
    , "[1:v]format=yuva444p,rotate=" + gifRotation + "*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(" + gifRotation + "*PI/180):oh=roth(" + gifRotation + "*PI/180),scale=h=" + gifHeight + ":w=" + gifWidth + ":[overlay_scaled],[0:v][overlay_scaled]overlay=eval=init:x=" + gifXPositionOnVideo  + ":y=" + gifYPositionOnVideo
    , "-frames:v"
    , "900"
    , "-codec:a"
    , "copy"
    , "-codec:v"
    , "libx264",
    outputVideo
```

};

if you don't want rotate gif replace line after "filter_complex" with

```
"[1:v]format=yuva444p,scale=h=" + gifHeight + ":w=" + ifWidth + ":[overlay_scaled],[0:v][overlay_scaled]overlay=eval=init:x=" + gifXPositionOnVideo  + ":y=" + gifYPositionOnVideo
```

this is working perfect for me with infinite gif playing(untill the video end) and specific position of gif on video

Hope this work for you also :)